# postgres optimize scope search query

Tags: postgresql

I use postgres 10.4 in linux environment .

I have a query which is very slow when I run it.

the search using subject with arabic language is very slow.
also the problem exist with subject in different language.

I have about 1 million record per year.

I try to add index in the table transfer but the result is the same

```
 CREATE INDEX subject
  ON public.transfer
  USING btree
  (subject COLLATE pg_catalog."default" varchar_pattern_ops);
```

this is the query .

```
select  * from  (  with scope as (  
select unit_id from public.sec_unit  
  where emp_id= 'EM-001'and app_type in ('S','E')  ) 
  select CAST (row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY advsearch.correspondenceid)
  as VARCHAR(15)) as numline, advsearch.*   
  from (  
  SELECT Transfer.id AS id, CORRESP.id AS correspondenceId,    
  Transfer.correspondencecopy_id AS correspondencecopyId, Transfer.datesendjctransfer AS datesendjctransfer
  FROM  Transfer Transfer    
  Left outer JOIN correspondencecopy CORRESPCPY  ON Transfer.correspondencecopy_id = CORRESPCPY.id   
  Left outer JOIN correspondence CORRESP ON CORRESP.id  = CORRESPCPY.correspondence_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN scope sc  on sc.unit_id = Transfer.unittransto_id or sc.unit_id='allorg'    
  LEFT OUTER JOIN employee emp on emp.id = 'EM-001'    
  WHERE  transfer.status='1'   AND (Transfer.docyearhjr='1441' ) 
  AND  (Transfer.subject like '%'||'رقم'||'%')   
  AND ( sc.unit_id is not null )  
  AND (coalesce(emp.confidentiel,'0') >= coalesce(Transfer.confidentiel,'0'))  

  )
  advsearch    ) Searchlist
  WHERE Searchlist.numline='1'  
  ORDER BY Searchlist.datesendjctransfer
```

can someone help me to optimise the query

**updated**

I try to change the query.

I eliminate the use of scope.
I change it by simple condition.

I have the same result ( the same number of record )

but the problem is the same : the query is still very slow

```
select  * from  (  

  select CAST (row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY advsearch.correspondenceid)
  as VARCHAR(15)) as numline, advsearch.*   
  from (  
  SELECT Transfer.id AS id, CORRESP.id AS correspondenceId,    
  Transfer.correspondencecopy_id AS correspondencecopyId, Transfer.datesendjctransfer AS datesendjctransfer
   
  FROM  Transfer Transfer    
  Left outer JOIN correspondencecopy CORRESPCPY  ON Transfer.correspondencecopy_id = CORRESPCPY.id   
  Left outer JOIN correspondence CORRESP ON CORRESP.id  = CORRESPCPY.correspondence_id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN employee emp on emp.id = 'EM-001'    
  WHERE  transfer.status='1' and ( Transfer.unittransto_id in ( 
  select unit_id from public.security_employee_unit  
  where employee_id= 'EM-001'and app_type in ('E','S') )
  or 'allorg' in ( select unit_id from public.security_employee_unit  
  where employee_id= 'EM-001'and app_type in ('S')))
  
    AND (Transfer.docyearhjr='1441' ) 
  AND  (Transfer.subject  like '%'||'رقم'||'%')  
  AND (coalesce(emp.confidentiel,'0') >= coalesce(Transfer.confidentiel,'0'))  

  )
  advsearch    ) Searchlist
  WHERE Searchlist.numline='1'  
  ORDER BY Searchlist.datesendjctransfer
```

**Updated :**

I try to analyze the query  using EXPLAIN ANALYZE

this the result :

```
"Sort  (cost=412139.09..412139.13 rows=17 width=87) (actual time=1481.951..1482.166 rows=4497 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: searchlist.datesendjctransfer"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 544kB"
"  ->  Subquery Scan on searchlist  (cost=412009.59..412138.74 rows=17 width=87) (actual time=1457.717..1480.381 rows=4497 loops=1)"
"        Filter: ((searchlist.numline)::text = '1'::text)"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 38359"
"        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=412009.59..412095.69 rows=3444 width=87) (actual time=1457.715..1477.146 rows=42856 loops=1)"
"              CTE scope"
"                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on security_employee_unit  (cost=8.59..15.83 rows=2 width=7) (actual time=0.043..0.058 rows=2 loops=1)"
"                      Recheck Cond: (((employee_id)::text = 'EM-001'::text) AND ((app_type)::text = ANY ('{SE,I}'::text[])))"
"                      Heap Blocks: exact=2"
"                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on employeeidkey  (cost=0.00..8.59 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.037..0.037 rows=2 loops=1)"
"                            Index Cond: (((employee_id)::text = 'EM-001'::text) AND ((app_type)::text = ANY ('{SE,I}'::text[])))"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=411993.77..412002.38 rows=3444 width=39) (actual time=1457.702..1461.773 rows=42856 loops=1)"
"                    Sort Key: corresp.id"
"                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2440kB"
"                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=18315.99..411791.43 rows=3444 width=39) (actual time=1271.209..1295.423 rows=42856 loops=1)"
"                          Filter: ((COALESCE(emp.confidentiel, '0'::character varying))::text >= (COALESCE(transfer.confidentiel, '0'::character varying))::text)"
"                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=18315.71..411628.14 rows=10333 width=41) (actual time=1271.165..1283.365 rows=42856 loops=1)"
"                                Join Filter: (((sc.unit_id)::text = (transfer.unittransto_id)::text) OR ((sc.unit_id)::text = 'allorg'::text))"
"                                Rows Removed by Join Filter: 42856"
"                                ->  CTE Scan on scope sc  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=2 width=48) (actual time=0.045..0.064 rows=2 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: (unit_id IS NOT NULL)"
"                                ->  Materialize  (cost=18315.71..411292.44 rows=10328 width=48) (actual time=53.970..635.651 rows=42856 loops=2)"
"                                      ->  Gather  (cost=18315.71..411240.80 rows=10328 width=48) (actual time=107.919..1254.600 rows=42856 loops=1)"
"                                            Workers Planned: 2"
"                                            Workers Launched: 2"
"                                            ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=17315.71..409208.00 rows=4303 width=48) (actual time=104.436..1250.461 rows=14285 loops=3)"
"                                                  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=17315.28..405979.02 rows=4303 width=48) (actual time=104.382..1136.591 rows=14285 loops=3)"
"                                                        ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on transfer  (cost=17314.85..377306.25 rows=4303 width=39) (actual time=104.287..996.609 rows=14285 loops=3)"
"                                                              Recheck Cond: ((docyearhjr)::text = '1441'::text)"
"                                                              Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 437299"
"                                                              Filter: (((subject)::text ~~ '%رقم%'::text) AND ((status)::text = '1'::text))"
"                                                              Rows Removed by Filter: 297178"
"                                                              Heap Blocks: exact=14805 lossy=44734"
"                                                              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on docyearhjr  (cost=0.00..17312.27 rows=938112 width=0) (actual time=96.028..96.028 rows=934389 loops=1)"
"                                                                    Index Cond: ((docyearhjr)::text = '1441'::text)"
"                                                        ->  Index Scan using pk_correspondencecopy on correspondencecopy correspcpy  (cost=0.43..6.66 rows=1 width=21) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=42856)"
"                                                              Index Cond: ((transfer.correspondencecopy_id)::text = (id)::text)"
"                                                  ->  Index Only Scan using pk_correspondence on correspondence corresp  (cost=0.42..0.75 rows=1 width=9) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=42856)"
"                                                        Index Cond: (id = (correspcpy.correspondence_id)::text)"
"                                                        Heap Fetches: 14227"
"                          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.28..8.31 rows=1 width=2) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=42856)"
"                                ->  Index Scan using pk_employee on employee emp  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=2) (actual time=0.038..0.038 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                      Index Cond: ((id)::text = 'EM-001'::text)"
"Planning time: 1.595 ms"
"Execution time: 1487.303 ms"
```

Comment: You need to provide additional information as described [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions#Information_You_Need_To_Include)

Comment: thank you for your response, I have updated my question, I try to change the query but it still very slow. I think that I must use union in my query to optimize the query

Comment: It would help if we could see the results of EXPLAIN ANALYZE although the usual suspect is the LIKE '%...%'

Comment: thanks, I try to analyze the query using EXPLAIN ANALYZE and I have updated my question.  I use EXPLAIN ANALYZE with the first query select  * from  (  with scope as ( .....